# SQL триггер должен проверить, существует ли таблица

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер

не могу понять как сделать это задание.
Триггер должен будет проверить, существует ли такая таблица в БД, и если нет, он сначала создаст ее, а затем перезапишет соответствующие данные. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

```
    delimiter //
create trigger tr_smazane_zapisy
    after delete
    on predmet
    for each row
begin
    if exists(select *
              from information_schema.TABLES
              where TABLE_NAME = 'smazane_zapisy')
        then
        insert into smazane_zapisy
        (semestr, jmeno,
         specializace, nazev, znamka)
        select distinct semestr, jmeno, specializace, OLD.nazev, znamka
        from zapis,
             student
        where student.rc = zapis.rc
          and zapis.kod = old.kod;
        end if;
end;
delimiter ;
```

Сама таблица:

```
create table smazane_zapisy
(
    semestr      CHAR(5),
    jmeno        VARCHAR(50),
    specializace VARCHAR(10),
    nazev        VARCHAR(20),
    znamka       INT
);
```

Comment: Что-то мне крайне сомнительно создание таблицы в триггере.

Comment: Таблицу следует создать одновременно с созданием триггера. То есть `create table ...`, `create trigger ...`. Из кода триггера убираем создание таблицы, оставляем запись данных.